# How to handle outliers by imposing limits using pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, outliers

I have two dataframes like as shown below

```
df_data = pd.DataFrame({'temp' :[-138,36,34,38,237,339],'heart_rate':[0,0,28,31,25,238]})

df_limit = pd.DataFrame({'reading' :['min_temp','min_heart_rate'],'min_val':[30,24],'max_val':[39,32]})
```

[image]    [image]

I already tried handling outliers using `sd` and `IQR` but they seem to be influenced by data distribution and still give me outliers in the data.

```
Q1 = dfx.quantile(0.25)
Q3 = dfx.quantile(0.75)
IQR = Q3 - Q1
print(IQR)
```

So, what I would like to do is impose the `min` and `max` conditions to the data.

Meaning, if you look at the `df_limit` dataframe, you will get the `min` and `max` limits for a specific paramter like `min_temp` or `min_heart_rate`.

Any value which violates these condition, has to be replaced with the default `min` (if it violates `min` criteria) and `max` (if it violates `max` criteria) value as shown below. Please note my real data has more than million rows and 70 columns. Any scalable approach is helpful.but yes, I have the limits for all these columns in a dataframe like `df_limit`

I expect my output to be like as shown below. you can see the `violated values` are replaced by default `min` and `max` values

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.clip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html) with extract minimal and maximal values from `df_limit`:

```
df_limit = df_limit.set_index('reading')

df_data['temp'] = df_data['temp'].clip(df_limit.loc['min_temp','min_val'],
                                       df_limit.loc['min_temp','max_val'])
df_data['heart_rate'] = df_data['heart_rate'].clip(df_limit.loc['min_heart_rate','min_val'], 
                                                   df_limit.loc['min_heart_rate','max_val'])
print (df_data)
   temp  heart_rate
0    30          24
1    36          24
2    34          28
3    38          31
4    39          25
5    39          32
```

If possible create general solution:

```
df_limit = df_limit.set_index('reading')

for c in df_data.columns:
    df_data[c] = df_data[c].clip(df_limit.loc[f'min_{c}','min_val'],
                                 df_limit.loc[f'min_{c}','max_val'])
```

Comment: @anky_91 - yop, `clip` is nice function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
def remove_outlier_by_capping(df1,df2,column):
    upper_lim = df2.loc[column,'max_val']
    lower_lim = df2.loc[column,'min_val']

    df1.loc[(df[column] > upper_lim),column] = upper_lim
    df1.loc[(df[column] < lower_lim),column] = lower_lim
```

```py
remove_outlier_by_capping(df_data,df_limit,'min_temp')
```

Comment: haven't tested but should work after changing accordingly